# Resize image to fit exactly within (Matplotlib) GridSpec Axes

Tags: image, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

How do you fit/resize/mask an image to fit (exactly) within a column cell using Matplotlib's Gridspec?

The below code requires a fudge factor of 53 to resize the image to fit (exactly) within the cell.

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
%config InlineBackend.figure_formats = {'png', 'retina'}
%matplotlib inline

side = 10 
nrows=5 
ncols =5
fudge = 53

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=5, ncols=5, wspace=0, hspace=0, 
                       width_ratios=[1,1,1,1,1], 
                       height_ratios=[1,1,1,1,1])

axes = {}

######################
# Thumbnail Image Column

for i in range(0,nrows):
    axes[i] = plt.subplot(gs[i,0])
    axes[i].set_xlim(0,10)
    axes[i].set_ylim(0,10)
    axes[i].axis("on")

    # Add Grey Square
    square = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), side, side, fc='b', hatch='///', linewidth=1, color='grey' )
    axes[i].add_patch(square)

    bbox = axes[i].get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
    width, height = bbox.width, bbox.height
    width *= fig.dpi *2
    height *= fig.dpi*2

    print(width,height, fig.dpi)
    #print(fig.dpi, bbox.width, width, bbox.height, height)

    # Trying to Mask/Resize the Image so it fits within the Column Cell
    img = Image.open("./images/test_500x500_pixel.png")
    #img_crop = img.crop((0, 0 ,width, height)) # Not using crop

    img.thumbnail((width+fudge, height+fudge), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=1, alpha=1)
    ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy=(0,0),
                        xycoords='data',
                        frameon=False,
                        box_alignment=(0,0),
                        boxcoords = None,
                        pad=0.0  
                       )
    axes[i].add_artist(ab)  
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
```

I'm trying to get the image to fit within the column cell--regardless of figure size. This column holds thumbnail images. The other columns are data extracted from a python pandas dataframe.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There cannot be a general answer to this question. Can you explain therefore more in detail the requirements you have on the image? Does it have to keep it's aspect? How much can you maximally crop? Is the background such that one could add a solid color?

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarify. The image needs to keep its aspect ratio--images are faces. The src images are 500x500 pixels. If possible, I'd rather these images be resized over cropped. Depending on the figure size and the size of the cell, I'd like the image to auto-resize into the 1.0 aspect ratio cell. In the chart, each row has a face image column followed by data columns. Re the backgroud color, I 'thought' drawing rectangle (with xlim and ylim) would set the size of the axes for the image to scale into. Didn't work out that way. Don't need the colored background rect– just the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following very simple code gives an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltBO1.png) column with equal aspect ratio.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = plt.imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltBO1.png")

N = 5
fig, ax = plt.subplots(N,2, figsize=(5,8))

for i in range(N):
    thisimage = np.copy(image)
    thisimage[:,:,0] = thisimage[:,:,0]*(i+1)/float(N)
    ax[i,0].imshow(thisimage)
    ax[i,0].set_xticks([])
    ax[i,0].set_yticks([])
    ax[i,1].plot(np.random.rand(9))

plt.show()
```

It produces the following plot.
[image]

It is not clear to me in how far this would not fulfil the requirements?

Comment: Thank you :) That worked with Gridspec as well. Apparently, my method of adding the image through AnnotationBBox followed by  matplotlib's add_artist method was screwing with the resizing. Your method is way simpler/saner. I'll post the final code on Monday with it working within Gridspec. Again, much appreciation.